# Laravel 5 - User Profile Images

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Having a slight problem with an application I'm working on..

I have the following tables:

```
1. Users

   id, 
   first_name,
   last_name

2. File_uploads
   id, 
   name, 
   location

3. profile_link
   id, 
   user_id, 
   file_id
```

Inside profile link, I have set that (`user_id`) is a foreign key to `id` on `Users` and `file_id` is a foreign key to `id` on `file_uploads` table.

I have created a model called `Fileuploads` and added the following into the `User` model:

```
  public function profile_image()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Fileuploads');
 }
```

Since the user will have 1 file upload in the users section, i.e. their profile image. I am getting the following error when trying to access:

```
$user = \App\User::find(2);
dd($user->profile_image)

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'file_upload.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `file_upload` where `file_upload`.`user_id` = 2 and `file_upload`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)
```

But I am not attempting to access `user_id` on the `file_uploads` because that's why I have a link table, but in this instance it doesn't look like it's registering it.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

If the record in `file_uploads` is changed to the same id as the user '2' and I use: `return $this->hasOne('App\Fileuploads', 'id', 'id');` then the profile is found straight away. But how can I do this, linking up to the link table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using a pivot table to link up your file_uploads you need to use the [`hasManyThrough()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

There is no method for has-one-through so you could just return the first result in the collection returned.

Answer (score 3):

The relationship your tables describes is a many-to-many between `Users` and `File_uploads` using `profile_link` as your link table.

If you use [belongsToMany()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) instead of `hasOne()` on the `profile_image` relationship, you can get it to handle the link table for you. Something like this:

```
public function profile_image()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Fileuploads', 'profile_link', 'user_id', 'file_id');
}
```

Because this is being modelled as a many-to-many, it's expected that there would/could be > 1 `File_uploads` record per user, so you'd get a collection back and need to access it like this:

```
$user = \App\User::find(2);
dd($user->profile_image[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works :)! But, the user should only be allowed 1 profile image.. This would allow for multiple profile images, yes?

Comment: If you're using a link table, it implies that you're expecting it to be a many-to-many, the reason you're doing that may well be completely valid for other reasons, but there's no way at the database level, or within Eloquent to enforce that only a single record exists on the other end. You'd need to implement that with application logic, or change the data model to directly link `Users` to  `File_uploads` with a `file_id` column on the `Users` record to indicate the single file that represents the profile image

Comment: Got it, thank you! Would it therefore be difficult if I was to select the latest one? (In the file_upload) table, there is 'uploaded_at' which is a date time, I could just pull out the latest one

Comment: You're better off just making sure the records in `profile_link` are correct - i.e. it only has a single record per user, and the `File_uploads` record that it points to is the one you're interested in. My earlier comment about there not being a database-level way to do this isn't actually correct ; you could create a unique index on  `profile_link.user_id` and that will mean each user can only be linked to one file via that table.